# Xcode changing between views

Tags: xcode, view, program-entry-point

When I try going to a second view i added in Xcode by linking a button on the toolbar, the code crashes and says Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT in the main at line  return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([JKGAppDelegate class]));  How do I stop it from crashing?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say without more information. First, you have to identify the source of the crash. See [My App Crashed, Now What?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) for guidance on how to identify the source of your crash. And often, just setting an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) for "all exceptions" can help you identify the source of the problem. I'd also suggest running your code through the static analyzer (press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in Xcode or choose "Analyze" on the Xcode "Product" menu) and make sure you have a clean bill of health there, with no issues reported.

Once you've identified the code that is causing the exception, post a new question with the code snippet of the offending code. When you post that code, let us know if you're using ARC or not and if you have a stack trace, share that, too.